# Django admin shows wrong translation

Tags: django, internationalization, nginx, django-admin, fastcgi

The problem is strange. Half of the admin inscriptions is translated to wrong language. I use **ru** and **en** languages in my project. The sites renders with the right language, but in the same browser admin appears as you can see in image:

[image]

I have **locale** folder in my app with **en** and **ru** locales, **.po** and **.mo** files are there...

settings.py:

```
LANGUAGES = (
    ('ru', gettext(u'Русский')),
    ('en', gettext(u'English')),
)
```

Trying different web-browsers... Browser sends following string in a header:

```
Accept-Language: ru-ru,ru;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
```

Problem is only in admin pages...

**UPD 1:**

With help of Diego the problem is localized, but not solved. With **runserver** everything is look good. But under **fastcgi+nginx** it doesn't work...

[image]

Comment: Are you using the method _() in the verbose name of class Meta in your models?https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/options/#verbose-name

Comment: Yes, sure! All the values of meta and fields of models is wrapped in _().

Comment: What version of django? maybe if you add me in gtalk we can go faster with this issue: diegueus9 at gmail dot com

Comment: The solution for me is to use ugettext_lazy instead of ugettext

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have

`fastcgi_pass_header  "Accept-Language";`

In your nginx conf.

Comment: He has builtin apps translated.

Comment: Public  part of my app traslated all right under nginx. The problem in admin part only.